# How to get 2d list find count python?

Tags: python

I want to get the list count, but I don't know how to get 2d list count.

```
the_string = raw_input()
COLS, ROWS = the_string.split()
two_string = raw_input()
co, ro = two_string.split()


Mylist= [[0 for cols in range(int(COLS))] for rows in range(int(ROWS))]
print(Mylist)

for cols in range(int(co)):
        for rows in range(int(ROWS)):
                Mylist[rows][cols]=1

for rows in range(int(ro)):
        for cols in range(int(COLS)):
                Mylist[rows][cols]=1
print(Mylist)

d = sum(row.count('1') for row in Mylist)


print(d)
```

This is the output I think:

```
d = sum(row.count('1') for row in Mylist)
```

It is wrong, but I can't change it.

This is the result:

```
3 4 
2 1
```

is just input.

```
3 4
2 1
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
0
```

Why '0'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you try to be more clear about what are you pretending with this code? And also provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: There are no `'1'` objects in your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue is that you are counting the occurrences of the string `"1"` with `.count()`, not the numerical value `1`. Instead, try:

```
d = sum(row.count(1) for row in Mylist)
```

Substituting this into your program and running:

```
3 4
2 1
```

Yields:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
9
```

Comment: @dani when I make the change, it returns `9` for me. I'll update my answer with the output I receive.